# Django CSRF cookie not set in several browsers

Tags: django, cookies, csrf, django-csrf

I have very strange problem - CSRF cookie not set on some of clients browsers. What could it potentially be?

All needed middleware is enabled, and as I said above, problem appears only on very small count of machines, although another Django-powered sites work well there.

Comment: Does the pages you are experiencing this behavior on contain the `{% csrf_token %}` tag?

Comment: Sure, and the app is working in most of browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem didn't solved in usual way, so I refused from cookie-based CSRF-protection and get session-based instead: https://github.com/mozilla/django-session-csrf.